# How to plot and print in the same cell in Python on Databricks?

Tags: python, plot, printing, databricks

How can I print something after plotting something in Python on Databricks?

There is an example of code I am running on Databricks:

```py
x = np.linspace(0,2,10)

plt.plot(x,x)

plt.show()

print("Hello World")
```

Expected answer :

```
[plot]

'Hello World'
```

Python version: 3.7.10

Comment: What was the output ? Provide more code and explain which steps you went in please :)

Comment: if Databrick uses `Jupyter` then maybe you should use `Jupyter` functions to display text. OR maybe you should add text directly to plot as `subplot`

Comment: Thank you for answers. I am running the above code on Databricks but I only have the plot. I would like to print something after the plot but it doesn't work with a simple print statement after plt.plot(...). I tried to ad plt.show(block=False) but it doesn't resolve my problem. I don't know what to do...

Comment: @WitzigAdrien thank you for your answer. Actualy I don't need to provide more code. If I run only this code I have the plot but I can't have "Hello World" printed. Do you know why?

Comment: @PierreJ i think you need to plot after the print

Comment: Unfortunately I doesn't work no matter where the print statement is. It seems to be the plot that covers the print statement because when I do a for loop which print 100 times "Hello World" before plotting something, I can see the prints but  when the plot is running all the prints desappear...

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?